# In a javascript game is it possible to completely prohibit the user from tampering with the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security

I'm starting to put together an online game in which the majority of the game is written in javascript. It occurred to me from a security perspective that with tools like FireBug that the player of the game could easily manipulate the javascript and do things that the game did not intend (e.g. enable the character to jump twice as high).

It gets even worse if I setup a feature to publish the scores to a scoreboard. Not only would the player be able to get inaccurate scores, but if they figured out how the scores were posted to the server then they could construct an AJAX call from FireBug to publish whatever score they wanted.

This particular problem is with gaming, but the core issue is with JavaScript security which can be applied to many other web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is absolutely not possible.

You can use obfuscation, you can make your AJAX really ugly, and in the end it will take someone at most 5 minutes to get around any client-side security you use.

You need to do checking for anything that is security related server-side, including scoring.  How to do this depends on your implementation.

Comment: I think 5 minutes is an exaggeration. Obfuscation can make it quite time consuming to figure out what to change where. However, someone somewhere will do it.

Comment: @SarelBotha, I doubt it.  Obfuscate your code all you want, and I'll fire up Fiddler and/or Wireshark and very quickly figure out what you're sending over the wire, and how.  Plus, there are several good tools available for cleaning up that JS.  I think 5-minutes to break it is a very reasonable time.

Comment: Now if the thing to protect is the data going across the wire then you could also implement data encoding to complicate things. Again, it can be figured out; it just makes it more time consuming.

Comment: Could those tools decrypt SSL?

Comment: @Adam, SSL can easily be worked around by Fiddler.  It installs itself as a proxy that will pass SSL, and can serve up its own certs.  SSL does make packet sniffing much more difficult however, but there are so many other attack vectors that it almost isn't worth worrying about, provided you aren't sending sensitive data over the wire that other eavesdroppers could read.

Comment: @Adam it doesn't need to: SSL is there to stop you seeing what is transmitted over someone else's connection; It has no effect on one's ability to manipulate the data that travels over one's own connection.

Comment: @Brad and Cheekysoft - Two very good points. Thanks for the insight. Rather than serve the game to a browser, if I embed Webkit in my own client app, disable view-source, and encrypt messages using Public Key/Private Key I wonder if that would work.

Comment: @Adam: that's effectively just more obfuscation. Ultimately you cannot trust anything that executes on hardware you don't control. Large commercial games developers have thrown a lot of resources at attempting to do so, with little success.

Comment: @Brad I posted a simple implementation in my answer that will definitively stretch the 5 minutes to ...?

Answer (score 3):

If the code is being run in a normal web browser, no it is not possible to protect it as you desire. However, you can validate events server side to make sure the actions taking place "make sense" so the user couldn't send you a score thats way to high or something. This does of course complicate your programming in non-trivial ways.

Answer (score 2):

Make lots of checks. If the max jump is 5 blocks high, make sure the server isn't accepting jumps higher than 5.

When I make games, I check for every single thing. Even if there is a 1% chance a user will do something to hack that certain thing, it's still protected.

Comment: Good suggestion. e.g. MMOs and some poker systems take a similar response to determine when one is trying to cheat the system. It's a good idea to transfer state and actions as often as possible to the server and have the server determine if the delta from one state to the next is reasonable or not and is consistent with the all the action-data that has been received throughout the session, for the time taken.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can protect your game. For example, by letting cheaters solve an extremely hard puzzle that uses misdirection.

## Context example

Consider a game that is completely dependent on javascript, and there is no server-side game-state. During the game, points are collected, and at the end of the game, these points are sent to the server to put the player on a leaderboard.

## Leaderboard problem

The most critical part of the game is that somebody can monitor network traffic, and change it as they wish. All other aspects in the game can be prevented by keeping a game-state on the server, but that is out of the scope of my answer.

## Implementing a "Security Key"

Consider that you keep track of points in a javascript object like this:

```
results = [
    {score: 12, epoch_ms: 15236543784, security_key: 6b42535e89f7fb1cc5abbe53d267ee0e},
    {score: 4, epoch_ms: 15236542565, security_key: 8af02a3d473d6b9c0a0362cfa59567d8},
    {score: 5, epoch_ms: 15236564511, security_key: 40f6611ff3156d935f420eb746ac897f}
];
```

On server-side, the `security_key` is checked with the whole packet `{score: ?, epoch_ms: ?}`. If it fails, then a demotivating message is returned from server: "**Error. Security key incorrect. Next time this happens, your account will be banned due to cheating.**" How to prevent people from making new accounts all the time is out of scope of this answer, but there are definitely very good ways to do this.

## How to generate a security key

The code to generate the `security_key` could be something like this:

```
result.security_key = your_over_the_top_complicated_algorithm(result, md5(result));
...
function your_over_the_top_complicated_algorithm(result, seed)
{....}
...
```

Now, the `security_key` is created with a very obfuscated and complicated algorithm that uses very lengthy regular expressions and whatever. Make sure that anyone trying to figure out how it works, that it takes at least a week to properly understand it (you could update your algorithm radically every week, to demotivate any further reverse engineering).

For this code to work, you also have to include an existing library that implements the used hash algorithm (`md5.js`), the use of these hashes can also be embedded into your complicated algorithm, as long as the library is a separate file.

## Fooled

The trick is that - while the cheater is trying to determine how to defeat that complicated algorithm - when `result` is passed as a reference somewhere to an external minified hashing function like `md5`. However, the external md5 function is actually our own modified version, we added a little bit of code to it, which sacrifices precision of the epoch of the `result.epoch_ms` value to store a hash based on the score (and possibly other elements in the result-object).

For example.
If the `epoch_ms` is equal to "`15236564511`" and the `score` is "`5`". Then when we call somewhere along the line `md5(result)` to function as a seed to our over-the-top-complicated-function.
But meanwhile, in that external md5-code...

```
 function md5(r)
 {
     ...
     r.epoch_ms=(r.epoch_ms+'').slice(0, -2)+(1234.56*r.score+'').slice(1,3);
     // or obfuscated (to prevent searching for terms like 'epoch_ms'):
     var _0x5da4=["\x65\x70\x6F\x63\x68\x5F\x6D\x73","\x73\x6C\x69\x63\x65","","\x73\x63\x6F\x72\x65"];r[_0x5da4[0]]= (r[_0x5da4[0]]+ _0x5da4[2])[_0x5da4[1]](0,-2)+ (1234.56* r[_0x5da4[3]]+ _0x5da4[2])[_0x5da4[1]](1,3)
     ...
 }
```

When the last two numbers of `epoch_ms` do not match the simple hash based on the `score`, then the server will return the same error as if the `security_key` is invalid. This is an essential part of the misdirection.

## Beware

This approach is a nobrainer to implement. There is no trade-off. The problem is that the solution to this puzzle is hidden in plain sight. As soon as the misdirection fails, and somebody inspects the `md5.js` file and looks for usages of `r`, it is "game over".

Also note that **I just made this up myself and have not personal experience with whether this is enough to stop cheaters in a javascript-based webgame. I may have overlooked a huge weakness of this approach.** Please comment if you find a weakness, it's an underdeveloped idea, so be nice :)

This is **not** cryptographically secure at all, and as with all anti-cheat systems, eventually somebody will figure it out. I guess the trick is to make it as difficult as possible with the least implementation effort.

Even though this is a relatively simple example, with enough obfuscation, steganography, a strict ban policy (it is likely that the cheater will make a mistake on first try), further improvements, and simplicity of the implementation it seems a nice extra precaution to take. Using the md5-function to hide code is just one of the many variants. You can think of many different ways to misdirect and demotivate a potential cheater.

It is kind of like a reinforced door to your house. They can't just kick the door in anymore, but need to spend more time to get in.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please give constructive feedback in a comment?